# Jest Vue3 The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

Tags: jestjs, vuejs3

I have this error after executing `npm run test:unit`.

Anybody knows what it's happening?

Regards

Mariano

```
$ npm run test:unit
> 04.fundamentos@0.1.0 test:unit
> vue-cli-service test:unit
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "04.fundamentos",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "test:unit": "vue-cli-service test:unit"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.8.3",
    "vue": "^3.2.13"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^2.0.0-rc.18",
    "@vue/vue3-jest": "^27.0.0-alpha.1",
    "babel-jest": "^27.0.6",
    "jest": "^27.0.5"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution....
For some reason test:unit is not working but if you replace the command name for other, like 'test' in the package.json, works fine

```
"test": "vue-cli-service test:unit"
```